# Remove Entries from Array starting from specific character

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, lastindexof

I have an array list that I need to modify to get rid of all the entries starting from the word that contains the period and earlier.

For example :

```
arrayList(0)= My
arrayList(1)= Name
arrayList(2) = Is
arrayList(3) = David.
arrayList(4) = How
arrayList(5) = Are
```

I need to remove arrayList(0-3)

I tried using:

```
dim pIndex = arrayList.LastIndexOf(arraylist.contains("."))
arrayList.RemoveRange(0,pIndex)
```

but just returns pIndex=-1 (meaning it can't be found)

How can I get the index of the entry with a period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LastIndexOf` returns the index of a specific element. `contains` return `True` or `False` if **the list** contains or not the element yo pass as parameter. Following your example, `arrayList.contains(".")` returns `False` because none of the elements of the list is "."; then `arrayList.LastIndexOf(false)` returns -1 because none of the elements of the list is `False`.

You need to iterate throught the list:

```
arrayList(0) = "My"
arrayList(1) = "Name"
arrayList(2) = "Is"
arrayList(3) = "David."
arrayList(4) = "How"
arrayList(5) = "Are"

Dim pIndex As Integer
For pIndex = arrayList.Capacity - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If arrayList(pIndex).ToString.Contains(".") Then Exit For
Next

If pIndex <> -1 Then arrayList.RemoveRange(0, pIndex + 1)
```

(Not tested, but it should do the work)

Comment: Should be fine if you change `Capacity` to `Count`.

Answer (score 1):

Why ArrayList?  If you use a List(Of String) then have much nicer tools at your disposal:

```
    Dim L As New List(Of String)
    L.Add("My")
    L.Add("Name")
    L.Add("Is")
    L.Add("David.")
    L.Add("How")
    L.Add("Are")

    Dim index As Integer = L.FindLastIndex(Function(x)
                                               Return x.Contains(".")
                                           End Function)
    If index <> -1 Then
        L.RemoveRange(0, index + 1)
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To L.Count - 1
        Debug.Print(i & ": " & L(i))
    Next
```